# How to prevent printing space after HTML element in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I want to output a formated name string with lastname in bold font. Like this:

**LASTNAME**, Firstname

In Angular I would typically doing this in the HTML template:

```
<strong>{{ lastname | uppercase }}</strong>, {{ firstname }}
```

But because of the `strong`-tag it will auto-insert a "space" after the tag and results in:

**LASTNAME** , Firstname

So how can I prevent that the additional `space` is printed in the HTML template?

Comment: Probably not `<strong>{{lastname|uppercase}}</strong>, {{firstname}}`? Dropping spaces

Comment: Please, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: My thought was, that the space after `{{` did maybe remain after the template was filled in with `lastname`. But evidently I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am not able to replicate the issue, please find below the CSS to get rid of any extra space. If not please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated, you need to do inspect element on that particular `strong` tag and check the computed tab, where that extra space is added

html

```
<div>
  <strong>{{ lastname | uppercase }}</strong>
  <span>, {{ firstname }}</span>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './main.html',
  standalone: true,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  lastname = 'Lastname';
  firstname = 'Firstname';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i1iuno)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. BTW: `margin-width` is not a valid CSS tag.

Comment: @Lars please could you replicate the issue in the stackblitz and share back

Comment: Here it comes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i1iuno?embed=1&file=src%2Fmain.ts I guess I could find the reason but not a solution: in VSCode my code formatter is moving the `,` and the `{{ firstname }}` to the next line automatically. This results then in the additional space (see example)